# Using images in Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm using Hyperledger Composer and Hyperledger Fabric to implement a blockchain application. Here, there is a requirement to publish images of a certain asset in the network. According to my knowledge, it's not a good practice to use images in a blockchain network. Any suggestions to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the further application of the your chained data. 

Maybe instead of images you can put inside SHA-2/SHA256 of these images.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store them on the blockchain, you're back to a centralized solution. Depending on your needs, that might be acceptable, or not. If you need to store it on the blockchain, you might use the url:data format, which lets you store them as strings, but any modern browser would be able to display them without additional code.